# Spring request mapping with Paypal

Tags: spring, jsp, paypal

For the return URL, it seem you have to define the whole URL like so:

```
String returnURL = "http://localhost:8080/appName/shopping/confirmorder";
```

Now, I have a problem with the request mapping:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/shopping/confirmorder?token={token}&PayerID={payerID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String doGet(@PathVariable("token") String token, @PathVariable("payerID") String payerID,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    // do stuff
}
```

The controller is never called for some reason?

The final returnURL returned from Paypal is like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/appName/shopping/confirmorder?token=EC-4...G&PayerID=A...W
```

Note the Ids have been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two path variables named `token` and `payerID`, then the method signature should be

```
public void doGet(@PathVariable("token") String token, 
                  @PathVariable("payerID") String token, 
                  HttpServletRequest request, 
                  HttpServletResponse response)
```

How did you expect Spring to put those two strings inside a single `option` parameter of type `int`?

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates

Moreover, PathVariable is used to bind portions of the request path to method arguments. In your case, you have request parameters. You should thus use @RequestParam:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/shopping/confirmorder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void doGet(@RequestParam("token") String token, 
                  @RequestParam("PayerID") String token, 
                  HttpServletRequest request, 
                  HttpServletResponse response)
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

Comment: Yeah thanks, just realised I copied the method, though it's not the problem.